# strtok problems I think

Tags: c, string, strtok

Can't figure this out, any help? I don't think this is strtok, I pretty sure it is my code. I can't figure out what thought. Get and Set are causing sigsevg. If I put a printf() after num = strtof, etc, the num is right, but the other commands arent being interpreted right.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    float height;
    float width;
    float length;
}Box;

void usage(void)
{

    printf("\nUsage: [command] [parameter] [amount]\n");
    printf("commands:\n\tSet\n\tGet\n");
    printf("parameters:\n\theight\n\twidth\n\tlength\n");
}


int main()
{
    usage();
    Box box1 = {0,0,0};
    int loop = 1;
    float num;
    char cp[65], *delims =  " !@#$%^&*():;/><.,\\?\"";
    char *tok1, *tok2, *tok3, *temp;

beginning:
    while(loop)
    {

        //Read the command from standard input
        char str[65];
        fgets(str, 64, stdin);
        str[64] = 0;

        //Tokenize the string
        strncpy(cp, str, 64);
        tok1 = strtok(cp, delims);
        tok2 = strtok(NULL, delims);
        tok3 = strtok(NULL, delims);

        //Check if tok3 is float
        num = strtof(tok3, &temp);
        if(num != 0)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            usage();
            goto beginning;
        }
        if(tok1 == 'Get' && tok2 == 'height')
        {
            printf("%f", box1.height);
        }
        else if(tok1 == 'Get' && tok2 == 'width')
        {
          printf("%f", box1.width);
        }
        else if(tok1 == 'Get' && tok2 == 'length')
        {
          printf("%f", box1.length);
        }
        else if(tok1 == 'Get')
        {
           usage();
           goto beginning;
        }

        if(tok1 == 'Set' && tok2 == 'height')
        {
          box1.height = num;
          printf("%f", box1.height);
        }
        else if(tok1 == 'Set' && tok2 == 'width')
        {
          box1.width = num;
        }
        else if(tok1 == 'Set' && tok2 == 'length')
        {
          box1.length = num;
        }
        else if(tok1 == 'Set')
       {
         usage();
         goto beginning;
       }

    }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: wrong label, I dont think strtok is the problem

Comment: If you're not going to use `temp`, you should probably just pass `NULL` to `strtof`: `num = strtof(tok3, NULL);`

Comment: `char cp[65], *delims =  " !@#$%^&*():;/><.,\\?\"";` Better declare `delims` as a `const char*`, like `const char* delims = " !@#$%^&*():;/><.,\\?\"";`

Answer (score 3):

```
if(tok1 == 'Get' && tok2 == 'height')
```

C strings have to use double quotes, and you can't test them equal using `==`, you should use [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/):

```
if(strcmp(tok1, "Get")==0 && strcmp(tok2, "height")==0)
```

About `strtof`:

```
num = strtof(tok3, &temp);
```

If you didn't have to use `temp`, use a null pointer:

```
num = strtof(tok3, NULL);
```

And the piece of code using `goto`:

```
if(num != 0)
{

}
else
{
    usage();
    goto beginning;
}
```

`goto` is ugly, use `continue` instead:

```
if(num == 0)
{
    usage();
    continue;
}
```

Comment: You *can* compare floating point numbers with `!=`; you just have to realize that imprecision and rounding occurs and that they may cause unintuitive results. In this case, no arithmetic is being performed and zero is exact, so that problem won't happen here.

Comment: You guys are incredible with the quick answers. I'm still catching a sigsevg at num =strtof(tok3, &temp)

Comment: `temp` is allocated, it's a `char*`. Note `strtof`'s second argument is a `char**`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not understanding. nothing I try is correcting this

Comment: @Toxor Compare to [this version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=883ec2dd04a3471c2bdc489979df3692-5189f3e4be2d016dc570170a200b8b1f), where I've tried to incorporate all suggested changes. Note I've added a `loop = 0;` at the end of the loop, but that's just for the online compiler.

Comment: Thank you guys. I had to put the num = strtof(tok3, NULL) in a if statement in case there was no tok3, my mistake. the strcmp arent working right, I'm trying to figure that one out

Comment: The strcmp(tok1, "Get") is returning 0, but strcmp(tok2, "height") is returning 1. Any ideas?

Comment: @Toxor New question, ***minimal*** complete (compilable) example, exact input and output.